# Nested For Expressions

Tags: scala

Is there a cleaner way, i.e. without the nested `for expressions`, to write the following `f`, `g`, and `doIt` functions?

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def f(x: Int): Future[Either[String, Int]] = Future(Right(100))

def g(x: Either[String, Int], y: Int): Future[Either[String, Int]] = 
   Future { x match {
    case Right(i)  => Right(i + y)
    case Left(err) => Left(err)
}}

def doIt: Future[Either[String, Int]] = for {
    x <- for { a <- f(100) } yield a
    y <- for { a <- g(x, 25) } yield a
} yield y
```

I'm speculating that I could use Monad Transformers, but I don't understand them.

Comment: Check out this really great talk: https://www.parleys.com/tutorial/options-futures-how-unsuck-them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're working with types like `Foo[Qux[A]]` where both `Foo` and `Qux` are monads and you find that you're writing a lot of nested `for`-comprehensions, the first thing you should do is check Scalaz (or [cats](https://github.com/non/cats)) for a `QuxT` monad transformer. That will allow you to work with `QuxT[Foo, A]` values monadically with a single level of `for`s.

As the other answers point out, you don't actually need the nested `for`-comprehensions in your case given your definition of `g`. I'm going to assume that you want to work with values all the way inside the `Future[Either[String, ?]]`, without the noisy `g` method, in which case you want an `EitherT[Future, String, Int]`:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def f(x: Int): EitherT[Future, String, Int] =
  EitherT.fromEither(Future[Either[String, Int]](Right(100)))

// Or just:
// def f(x: Int): EitherT[Future, String, Int] = EitherT.right(Future(100))

def doIt: EitherT[Future, String, Int] = f(100).map(_ + 25)
```

Eventually you'd write `doIt.run` to get a `Future[Either[String, Int]]`:

```
scala> doIt.run.onSuccess { case e => println(e) }
\/-(125)
```

Which is the same result your implementation gives (except that we've got Scalaz's disjunction type).

Comment: thank you, Travis. Does `without the noisy g method,` mean excluding the `Future[...]`, i.e. `def g(...): Either[String, Int]` rather than the outer wrapper of `Future`?

Comment: Your `g` seems to be an attempt to work around the fact that you've got two layers in `Future[Either[String, Int]]`—it's not doing anything interesting with the `Either`, and could be written more cleanly as a function from `Int` (or not written at all, as in my example).

Comment: Could you take a look at this one please - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31326958/nested-for-comprehensions-with-futures?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You don't need the nested `for`-comprehensions at all:

```
def doIt: Future[Either[String, Int]] = for {
  x <- f(100)
  y <- g(x, 25)
} yield y
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to part with `for` comprehensions fully:

```
def doIt: Future[Either[String, Int]] = f(100).flatMap(x => g(x, 25)
```

Or even shorter:

```
def doIt: Future[Either[String, Int]] = f(100).flatMap(g(_, 25)
```