# Nested For Comprehensions with Futures

Tags: scala

Given:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def f: Future[Either[String, Int]] = Future { Right(100)}

def plus10(x: Int): Future[Either[String, Int]] = 
    Future { Right(x + 10) }
```

I'm trying to chain the `Future[...]` together as so:

```
scala> for { 
     |  x <- f
     |  y <- for { a <- x.right } yield plus10(a)
     | } yield y
<console>:17: error: value map is not a member of Product with 
    Serializable with 
   scala.util.Either[String,scala.concurrent.Future[Either[String,Int]]]
        y <- for { a <- x.right } yield plus10(a)
                     ^
```

I am expecting to get: `Future{Right(100)}` as a result, but I get the above compile-time error.

Travis Brown gave an excellent answer on how to use Monad Transformers to fix my code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325358/nested-for-expressions). However, how can I fix my code **without** Monad Transformers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I can use `Either#fold`:

```
 scala> for { 
     |  a <- f
     |  b <- a.fold(_ => Future { Left("bad") }, xx => plus10(xx) )
     | } yield b
res16: scala.concurrent.Future[Either[String,Int]] = 
     scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@67fc2aad

scala> res16.value
res17: Option[scala.util.Try[Either[String,Int]]] = 
          Some(Success(Right(110)))
```

Comment: If you don't actually care about changing the left-hand side (as in the question), you can project right with `.right` and then `map`.

Comment: `scala> for { a <- f; b <- a.right.map(plus10(_)) } yield b` gives compile-time error: 
`<console>:15: error: value map is not a member of Product with Serializable with scala.util.Either[String,scala.concurrent.Future[Either[String,Int]]]`

Answer (score 1):

I was about to answer when yours appeared, but you might still look at this:

```
val res = for {
  x <- f
  y <- x.fold(x => Future{Left(x)}, plus10)
} yield y
```

It is a little more concise on the right side and keeps the left side.